# How to open a new xterm window and run a command on that window using fork-exec calls ? ( C program only)

Tags: c, pipe, fork, system, file-descriptor

Basically, I am learning *pipe* and *dup* system calls.

I want to take a command-name (like ls,cd,mkdir etc) as input from the parent process and pass it on to the child process using pipe, the child process should *open up a new xterm window* and show the man page of the command recorded in the pipe in this new xterm window.

The problem is that exec changes the whole process image of the child, so any code written after is simply ignored (if exec was successful).So if I exec the child to "/bin/xterm", then any exec calls in the child block are removed, as the process image changed to xterm.

So how do I call /bin/man?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  Do you want a way to exec /bin/man, or do you want a way to pass information to a child process you created?

Comment: You can just run `'/usr/bin/xterm' '-e' '/bin/man' 'command name you read from pipe here'` and let xterm do the second fork & exec for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you calling `fork` again - a process can have any number of children, grandchildren etc...

In this particular instance you need the child to `fork` and create grandchildren that `exec` "/bin/xterm" with your man command. And also handle clean up of them as they finish.